# OpenGL: Why this white scrreen

Tags: c++, opengl

Why I am getting a full White colored window as an output of this program
Expected a box

code is here

```
#include<Gl/glut.h>

static GLfloat vertices[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                          0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
                          0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
                          0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                          };

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
}

void Draw()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glArrayElement(0);
        glArrayElement(1);
        glArrayElement(2);
        glArrayElement(3);
    glEnd();
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("vectors");

    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Corrected GL_LINES to GL_QUADS

Comment: You never use `vertices` for anything.

Comment: I didnt get u moibdnilo. I have also changed the name if u were meaning that

Comment: Did all the changes which has been done same result genpfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple problems:

- `reshape()` is broken; `glOrtho()` multiples by the current matrix and will give nonsensical results if you resize the window more than once.
- You request a double-buffered (`GLUT_DOUBLE`) context but fail to swap the buffers.  `glFlush()` is insufficient.  Try `glutSwapBuffers()` instead.
- You really ought to reset your projection/modelview matrices each frame.  Helps prevent errors.

Give this a shot:

```
#include<Gl/glut.h>

static GLfloat vertices[] = 
{
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5,
    0.0, 0.5,
};

void Draw()
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices );

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glArrayElement(0);
        glArrayElement(1);
        glArrayElement(2);
        glArrayElement(3);
    glEnd();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("vectors");

    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: I want to learn glArrayElement() function thats why the code.

Comment: It was the glFlush(); which was creating that problem, Changed it to glutSwapBuffers(); worked

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is your call to `glVertexPointer()`. The last parameter is supposed to be a pointer to the start of the array you're using, but at the moment you're just passing it a null pointer, so it's got nothing to work with.

Try this instead:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
```

EDIT: By the way, your code won't give you a box. If it works, I think it'll just give you two lines. Try using GL_QUADS instead of GL_LINES.

Comment: I'm not sure how much GLUT does for you, but I suspect you're missing several other important operations. With normal OpenGL programs, you'd need to call `glSwapBuffers()` at the end of `Draw()`. I also think you should be calling `glViewport()` in your `reshape()` function. Additionally, you usually need to set the matrix mode to `GL_PROJECTION` before calling `glOrtho()` (and obviously switch it back to `GL_MODELVIEW` afterwards). GLUT may do some of that for you though, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

The main thing that pops out at me is the array: 
`//static GLfloat vertices[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, };`

should be

`static GLfloat vertices[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0 };`
(note the removed comma)

Next thing is the enabling and disabling of the client state: that could be done in the main loop for example as it is expensive to enable and disable and your draw loop will suffer because of it.

Comment: The first thing you pointed out here are just <ENTER> and they dont effect anything. Secondly, Yes, its taking a lot of time to load the windw but its Ok. I am more concerned about the output

Comment: I will try this code out on my dev machine tonight and get back to you:)